# Subversion: How to restore a file with history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My boss just ignored .vbp files and apparently deleted one of them from the repository in the process.  After explaining to him why he needs those files in source control, I am now tasked with putting it back.

Problem is I think that he might have added it back just after he told me to because now when I try to add it, it tells me it's already there.  But when I delete it from my drive and update , it doesn't get restored.  I'm afraid that if I delete it out of the repository and then add mine it's going to do the same thing on his end that's happening to me now.

Ideally I would like to just roll back to what was there before this mess started but can't quite figure out the right way to do it.  I know we can't roll back revisions in subversion, but it would still be nice to get it back in there with the history it had if possible.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using TortoiseSVN.  I can find the file using the log history, and I can check out a revision... but I don't want to checkout all the files.  I just want to get the one.  Still trying to figure out the best way to do this...

I looked at using blame but I may have to read up on that option cause it's not intuitively making sense to me at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring a file back, you just need to back-out the change that deleted it.

You may want to start with a clean checkout. Probably a good idea. Alternatively, it sounds like you just need to run `svn revert file.vbp` on your checkout (you probably have it added, but not comitted. `svn status` should tell you what's going on).

First, find the revision that deleted it with `svn log -v`. Then, to back out the change, change into the directory the file belongs in and use `svn merge -c -REVISION http://server/path/file`. Note the revision number is *negative*. Finally, run `svn commit` to commit the revert.

(Note: this doesn't lose history. The commit which deleted it will still be in history, there will just be a new commit restoring it. SVN should realize its the same file for things like `svn log`.)

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I forgot to mention I'm using TortoiseSVN and have never run a single svn command line... not that I'm opposed to learning, but just not right now :/

Comment: @BrandonMoore: With TortoiseSVN, its apparently even easier: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html You'll have to pick the folder, obviously, as you can't pick the file.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to do just the file but I may have to do it that way.  Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: You're picking just one revision, so assuming it was deleted alone, it is just that file. If other changes were made in that revision, after the merge, right-click the other files and revert them. Then just commit the one file you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [svn blame](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html) to look up when the file existed.

Then, when you have the proper revision name, use [svn update](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html) on that file's path.

Comment: Sorry... forgot to tag this as TortoiseSVN.  Maybe your solution is still best but I'll have to read up on blame.

Comment: Either way, just try to use the command line svn for restoring those files and then continue using TortoiseSVN. Good luck! :)

Comment: Not even sure how to do that :)  I may look into it though if I don't see how to do it with Tortoise.